# Correct closure reason for "code plz" questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, close-reasons

While I love the new closure reasons, I'm confused which one I should select when the user has requested code that implements his requirements.

E.g. "*I've got to make a JAva program that like sums all the numbers 1-10 LOL. Help!*"

The best match I can see is "**Off Topic > Minimal Understanding**":

[image: closure reason]

Is this the right selection? I almost feel like we need a separate closure reason that explains we do not provide free code.

Comment: The "specific problem" one also applies: "... include valid code to reproduce it".

Comment: @Yannis That was a close second in my eyes. But I thought it was an inferior choice because it begins with "*Questions concerning problems with code you've written...*", which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is in the case you specifies. It is also correct option if post has code but no details whats the problem with the code? or what should be the output? In general, all the post that are not complete or self describing issues lies in this closure status.

But if a post has no code but its describe in details the effort, background and output for the issue it should not be closed.